# Not able to copy the contents of one array to another in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have an empty array defined like this in my component:

```
private dtoList=[];
```

I call a service with HttpClient to fetch data from the backend that returns and object containing a list:

```
    this.appService.getData()
        .subscribe((response) => {
          let value = response;
            //1st way
          this.dtoList = response['dtoList'];
          //2nd way
          this.dtoList = cloneDeep(response['dtoList']);
   });
```

The response received in the value field is:

```
Object {success: false, description: null, dtoList: Array(2), status: null}
```

The list received in the response object is not getting copied in the target list.
The target list is always shown as undefined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `this.dtoList = response.dtoList;`  ?

Comment: what is your cloneDeep() ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `response` has that shape? Your syntax looks correct

Comment: response.dtoList is enough; response['dto List'] ->  [' ' ] is used when your key have a space

Comment: it should be ```response.json().dtolist``` .

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient` ?

Comment: HttpClient @trichetriche

Comment: @fatemefazli its showing: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: @trichetriche I think it should be using `HttpClient` because is taged as `angular5`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero never expect the tags to be correct ;)

Comment: @SalmanKazmi and could you make a console log of your resonse object ? Or is it the one your provided ?

Comment: @trichetriche Its the one I provided:Object {success: false, description: null, dtoList: Array(2), status: null}

Comment: @SalmanKazmi did you make the console log in the component or in the service ?

Comment: @trichetriche in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phenomenon that happens is not quite clear but if I copy the contents of the returned response in a separate method, it seems to work. So instead of copying the response contents in the anonymous subscribe function, I passed it to another method to copy. It worked this way.

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe((response) => {
        let values = response['dtoList'];
        this.copyValues(values);
});

// the copyvalues method

copyValues(list) {
    this.dtoList = list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`response['dtoList'].forEach(element=>{
 this.dtoList.push(element);
});`

Comment: this.dtoList is always undefined in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to clone your objects inside an array

```
this.appService.getData()
        .subscribe((response) => {
          response['dtoList'].forEach((obj, index) => this.dtoList[index] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
          console.log(this.dtoList)
});
```

Comment: this.dtoList is shown as undefined. Don't have an idea why.

Comment: Seems like your `response['dtoList']` itself is coming as empty. Can you verify that? Because you show `dtoList: Array(2)` in your object, which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
your declaration is wrong for private dtoList=[]; 

declare like  dtoList:any=[]; than assign object like below
 constructor(){
    this.dtoList={success: false, description: null, dtoList: ['dat1','data2'], status: null}
    console.log(this.dtoList);
    console.log(this.dtoList.dtoList);
  }
```

Comment: it did not work. The dtoList to which I am trying to assign is always shown as undefined.

Comment: convert your response in JSON.stringify(value)

Comment: this.dtoList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response['dtoList'])); but to no avail. The this.dtoList is always undefined.

Comment: this.dtoList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); than use console.log(this.dtoList.dtoList)

Answer (score 0):

Try please this way. Create `class(model)` for result list item, set generic `Observable` type for `getData` method.

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<ResultModel> {
    return this.http.get<ResultModel>('url for api');
  }

}

export class ResultModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
private dtoList: ResultModel[] = [];
 this.appService.getData()
    .subscribe((response) => {
        this.dtoList = response;
        // if here you want copy array, you can use spread operator
        // this.dtoList = [...response];
     });
```